# Rendering material tags using api response not working

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular8

I am trying to render the HTML which I am getting from the API response.

```
<div class="mainWrapper">
<mat-grid-list cols="11" class="layout layout7x5">
  <mat-grid-tile colspan=2 rowspan=2 class="column columnRight"> 
    <span class="optionSpan icon-A003-item1"></span>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan=1 rowspan=2 class="column columnMiddle"> 
    <span>=</span>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan=2 rowspan=2 class="column columnLeft"> 
    <span>JUB</span>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan=1 rowspan=2 class="columnBreak">
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan=2 rowspan=2 class="column columnRight"> 
    <span class="optionSpan icon-A003-item2"></span>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan=1 rowspan=2 class="column columnMiddle"> 
    <span>=</span>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan=2 rowspan=2 class="column columnLeft"> 
    <span>CIB</span>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <br>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan=2 rowspan=2 class="column columnRight"> 
    <span class="optionSpan icon-A003-item3"></span>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan=1 rowspan=2 class="column columnMiddle"> 
    <span>=</span>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan=2 rowspan=2 class="column columnLeft"> 
    <span>CUF</span>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan=1 rowspan=2 class="columnBreak">
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan=2 rowspan=2 class="column columnRight"> 
    <span class="optionSpan icon-A003-item4"></span>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan=1 rowspan=2 class="column columnMiddle"> 
    <span>=</span>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan=2 rowspan=2 class="column columnLeft"> 
    <span>JIF</span>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <br>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan=2 rowspan=2 class="column columnRight"> 
    <span class="optionSpan icon-A003-item5"></span>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan=1 rowspan=2 class="column columnMiddle"> 
    <span>=</span>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan=2 rowspan=2 class="column columnLeft"> 
    <span class="question">?</span>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

This is my HTML structure and I am rendering it using

```
<span [innerHTML]="getName(item) | textcontent: randomText | domsanitizemba"></span>
```

but mat-grid is not working as expected.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-grid-tile-with-icons-ewumz7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: You could've just returned the data in a JSON format and then have your application fit the returned data accordingly, instead of returning the HTML (which will not work without passing it through something like Angular's [dynamic component loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)).